# GitHub pull request commit is not listed in local git log

Tags: git, github

I submitted a pull request on GitHub which forked the repo and created a 'feature-1' branch on the forked repo. On github my commit is shown.

So far so good - there is `original_repo/app` and then the forked `my_repo/app` with my commit (PR) in `feature-1` branch.

Now I need to amend the commit message before it will be accepted and merged. Uh Oh.

If I clone the forked repo (`my_reo/app`) locally, checkout the `feature-1` branch,  and then run `git log`, my commit is not listed.

If I run `git commit --amend` I only see commits from `master` branch.

I can't amend the commit message. Why isn't my commit available locally to amend?

Comment: Maybe you can see your commit with `git log --oneline --all --decorate --graph` ?

Comment: @Asenar Yes, the commit shows up with that command.

Answer (score 0):

If you see commits from master branch, that's probably mean your are still on `master` branch.

To see more precisely «where you are», you can use

```
git log --graph --topo-order --all --oneline
```

This will display a graph will all commits of your repo, and all local and remote branches (--all --decorate). Your current branch name is where `HEAD` is located. You can also get your current branch name with the command `git branch`, indicated with a `*`.

So, it seems you need to go on `feature-1` branch, amend the last commit, then force-push this changes. This can be done with the following commands :

```
git checkout feature-1
git commit --amend
git push my_repo feature-1:feature-1 --force
```

Be careful in case your local branch `feature-1` has diverged from the remote branch `my_repo/feature-1` for some reason (if you worked from an other place).